# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given, error

Tags: php, mysql

I have read through many other threads about this exact problem, but i for some reason can not solve my problem. Really need some help.

Query is good, I tested it in phpmyadmin and result was:

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took
>   0.0004 seconds.)

**SOURCE**

```
    $items=array();

    $kwer="select distinct(d.id) as item, d.name, sd.date
        from sklad h
        inner join sent_item sd on sd.id_item = h.id
        inner join customers d on d.id=sd.id_customer
        where h.id=".$this->id." and sd.type=2
        order by sd.date, d.name asc";

    if($kwer === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    } else {

        if($kwer){
            $result = mysql_query($kwer);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            var_dump($result);
            //die;
            if (mysql_num_rows($kwer) != 0){

            $res=mysql_query($kwer);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
                    $items[]=$row->items;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
```

**ERROR**

```
resource(7) of type (mysql result) 
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /test.php on line 284
```

**EDIT:**

```
    $items=array();

    $kwer="select distinct(d.id) as item, d.name, sd.date
        from sklad h
        inner join sent_item sd on sd.id_item = h.id
        inner join customers d on d.id=sd.id_customer
        where h.id=".$this->id." and sd.type=2
        order by sd.date, d.name asc";

    if($kwer === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    } else {

        if($kwer){
            $result = mysql_query($kwer);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            var_dump($result);
            //die;
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
                while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                    $items[]=$row->items;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
```

Comment: `if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){`, not `$kwer`!!

Comment: Please, _stop using `mysql_*`,_ the extension [is ***deprecated*** (read the red box)](http://php.net/mysql_connect). Upgrade your PHP version, set the error level to `E_STRICT|E_ALL` and note the `E_DEPRECATED` warnings functions like `mysql_num_rows` emit. Also read up on injection and prepared statements....

Comment: On a sidenote, how can `$kwer` ever be false when you know for sure something is in there? You write the query yourself so the string will never be empty. Also watch your variable namings, it's important to use logical names. So instead of `$kwer`, you could say something like `$query` which would make alot more sense.

Comment: Do keep track of what your variables are and which you're passing to which function. You're simply mixing up your variables and probably variable names.

Comment: sorry i am beginner... and I hope stackoverflow is here not for those people who knows, but for those who dont know... ;)

Comment: Sure, but please do make a reasonable effort to debug your own code before posting it here. A simple debugging technique is to add `var_dump($var)` statements here and there to test and see what the actual values of your variables are, and to confirm that this matches both your expectation and the expectation of the functions you're passing those variables into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($kwer) != 0){
```

to

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
```